# MP3 resampling with torchaudio and ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, pytorch, torchaudio

I'm using `torchaudio` (version 2.0.2) to resample audio files. I'm trying to match the same results as `ffmpeg` (version 6.0). Specifically, the commands I use are:

```
waveform, sr = torchaudio.load(filepath)
transform = torchaudio.transforms.Resample(orig_freq=sr, new_freq=16000)
waveform = transform(waveform)
```

And the command for `ffmpeg` is:

```
ffmpeg -i source -ac 1 -ar 16000 target
```

What's the proper `torchaudio` code to achieve what `ffmpeg` is doing in this command? Thanks!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/162698)